# SyntaxError at Cloud9 IDE? Is this a bug or did I do something wrong?

Tags: python, syntax

I believe I have found a bug with the Cloud9 IDE, as I get a syntax error in the following code:

```
    for x in optionMenu:
            print x[0], x[1]
        action = raw_input ("Please select an action: ")
        if action == "1":
            direction = directionMenu()
            if direction == "East":
                validAction = True
                print "You raise the portcullis and enter the palace."
                room2(character)
            else:
                print "You can't go that way!"
        elif action == "2":
            characterMenu(character)
        elif action == "3":
            if searched_yet1 == False:
                skill_pass = skillCheck(1, character.search)
                if skill_pass ==  True:
                    print "The double portcullis seems moveable with some effort."
                    searched_yet1 = True
                else:
                    print "You fail to find anything worthy of note. "
                    searched_yet1 = True
            else:
                print "You have already attempted that action!"
        elif action == "4":
            if listened_yet1 == False:
                skill_pass = skillCheck(5, character.listen)
                if skill_pass == True:
                    print "Sounds coming from deep in the palace can be heard every few minutes."
                    listened_yet1 = True

                else:
                    print "You fail to hear anything worth of note. "
                    listened_yet1 = True
            else:
                print "You have already attempted that action!"
```

The syntax error occurs at `"elif action == "4":`. AmI doing something wrong or have I found a bug with the Cloud9 IDE? I have tried adjusting the spacing. Is there an error with the above print statement?

EDIT: Version is Python 2.7.6, error is

```
File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/dungeonMap.py", line 63
    elif action == "4":
   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I examine your code as posted here, the line `elif action == 4:` is preceded by 4 spaces then 2 tabs. Mixing spaces and tabs in Python is *a very bad idea*. I also see that some lines, such as the preceding one, use only spaces for indentation.

Replace those two tabs, as well as any others, with spaces, and configure your IDE to use only spaces when indenting. See if that solves the problem.

---

After looking more closely, I now see the direct problem. I believe that Python treats a tab as 8 spaces, no matter how it appears in your editor. Given that, your line two lines above your problem line is an `else:` but is indented to conclude the `if action == "1":` line rather than the `if searched_yet1 == False:` line that you intended. Python then sees your `elif action == 4:` line as an `elif` without a corresponding prior `if`.

Again, replacing all those tabs with spaces and then getting the indentation to look right will solve that problem and others.

Comment: I had no idea that tabs and spaces affected anything! I've heard of these things but I had no idea. I'll reconfigure my IDE

Comment: If you didn't know that indentation is a very important part of the Python syntax, how did you manage to write your code so far?

Comment: Well, I didn't know that tabs and spaces were different things, I mean.